# Getting an uncaught TypeError with iframe-resizer

Tags: iframe-resizer

I've installed it and all the calls are going across right up to the height set and then it dies.

```
[iFrameSizer][Host page: ts-vcsc-iframe-2283494] Checking width is in range 0-Infinity - iframeResizer.min_.js:8
[iFrameSizer][Host page: ts-vcsc-iframe-2283494] IFrame (ts-vcsc-iframe-2283494) height set to 1833px  - (index):888 

Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
 at resizedCallback ((index):888)
 at m (iframeResizer.min_.js:8)
 at I (iframeResizer.min_.js:8)
 at a (iframeResizer.min_.js:8)
 at t (iframeResizer.min_.js:8)
 at d (iframeResizer.min_.js:8)
 at J (iframeResizer.min_.js:8)
 at l (iframeResizer.min_.js:8)

iframeResizer.contentWindow.min_.js:9 [iFrameSizer][ts-vcsc-iframe-2283494] Trigger event lock off
iframeResizer.contentWindow.min_.js:9 [iFrameSizer][ts-vcsc-iframe-2283494] --
```

Suggestions as to why I'm getting this error? I downloaded the latest files from GitHub.

Comment: I finally figured it out. This code did the trick for me:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
 var iframes = iFrameResize({
  log: false, // Enable console logging
  inPageLinks: true,
  heightCalculationMethod: 'bodyScroll',
  checkOrigin: false
 });
});
</script>